# To marry OR Marriage? Japanese と in context

Tags: translation, particle-と

The phrase runs thus:

> お[姫様]{ひめ・さま}と[結婚]{けっ・こん}して。

Is it literally "married the princess" or does the と affect the subject in any way?

Comment: Are you sure it is `して` and not `した`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English it's "to marry someone" (direct object), in Japanese it's 誰か**と**結婚する "to marry [**with**] someone". So, yes, it is literally "marry the princess".

Comment: The phrase is 結婚して not 結婚した, so the literal translation should be the request "marry the princess”, not the past tense “married the princess”.